# Standalone is not working with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, standalone

I'm trying to use `standalone` with `circuitikz`, but it is not working, any ideas why?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american currents, american voltages, american inductors]
        \draw (0,0) 
        to[R, l=$Z$,i=$\mathbf{I}$,v_=$\mathbf{V}$,o-o]  (8,0)
        ;
        \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It works fine! BTW, you not need to load `tikz` package.

Comment: compiles and works fine --what do you feel is wrong

Comment: If you don't say _which_ error you have, nobody can help... the only thing I see it that you will have a loud `circutikz` warning becasue you didn't chose a voltage direction policy.

Comment: I have the same issue. The expected behavior is a cropped pdf around the circuit. Instead, the circuit is on an a4/letter page.